Selecting a MUI Dropdown menu item by default
I have a MUI dropdown that I am using as a status filter for a table.  the customer has requested that the table display Active items by default.  I was hoping to accomplish this by being able to pass a prop value that would select a value in the dropdown by default. That way I could uses different default values on different dropdowns since the component is reusable.  Is there a way to accomplish this?
here is my dropdown component:
function DropdownFltr(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const { error = null, options, prompt, onChange, value, ...other } = props;

  return(
    <>
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl} variant='outlined' >
        <InputLabel>{prompt}</InputLabel>
        <Select
            defaultValue='' // needed to make component controlled
            onChange={onChange}
            value={value}
            {...other}
            {...(error && {error: true, helperText: error})}
        >
            {options.map((option, id) => (
                <MenuItem
                    key={option.id}
                    value={option.value}
                >
                    {option.label}
                </MenuItem>
            ))}
        </Select>
    </FormControl>
    </>
    );
}

export default DropdownFltr;

I have tried setting the "defaultValue" inside the component, but it does not seem to do anything, but without it I get errors that the component is not controlled.
How I call the component from the page
const [filterFn, setFilterFn] = React.useState({ fn: items => items });
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState(``);


// --- THE DROPDOWN OPTIONS ---
const status = [
  { id: 1, label: '...', value: '' },
  { id: 2, label: 'Active', value: 0 }, 
  { id: 3, label: 'Inactive', value: 1 }
];


// --- DROPDOWN FILTER HANDLER ---
  const handleFilterValue = e => {
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value);
    const filterVal = (e.target.value).toString().toLowerCase();
    setFilterFn({
      fn: items => {
        if (filterVal === '') { return items; }
        else {
          return items.filter(x =>
            x.status.toString().toLowerCase().includes(filterVal)
          );
        }
      }
    });
  };


// --- THE DROPDOWN FILTER ---
  <DropdownFltr
    options={status}
    prompt='Status...'
    onChange={handleFilterValue}
    value={selectedValue}
  />

I then use filterFn to filter the table data as such, where I map through dataFilteredAndSorted to populate the table:
  const dataFilteredAndSorted = () => {
    return sortedTableData(filterFn.fn(searchFn.fn(tableData)), getComparator(order, orderBy));
  };

Is there a way to pass a prop,  like "defaultSelection", from the page view and have a value pre-selected in the dropdown?  Everything I have tried either does not work, or just cause the dropdown to stop working altogether.

defaultValue is for uncontrolled components. If you are controlling the component, you should set value from the parent.

Try setting the initial value for the selectedValue state.
